# Positive feedback in Islam?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, sunnah, life

In our life, we have some goals that sometimes we can fulfill and sometimes we fail. Among us, there are those who their love work and can move on even if the result is negative. And among us, there are those who need positive feedback to keep going. I am on the second team. At the end of the day, I need some kind of positive feedback to continue. But in islam, we dont get to see the status of our deeds in daily basis, so there is no way to know how much better I am getting from yesterday or if my deeds are at all count to something. On top of that, from worldly life perspective, when there are some kinds of failure, I seek peace in islam, but again there is no feedback because the result only can be seen in hereafter, there are no midterms or class tests where you can assess yourself, so it is difficult to be patient.

I know some of us are in love in Islam, love to pray and fear Allah. But as I am try to be a practicing muslim, the psychological issues I presented here, is keeping me from becoming one. So if anyone has a suggestion, it will be much appreciated.